# View config getter callback for component `RCTText` must be a function (received `undefined`)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have created a custom wrapper for text in RN and when I trying to import, It getting this error `View config getter callback for component 'RCTText' must be a function (received 'undefined')`. here is my code. I have tried to import View instead of Text and its working. Can't find the exact issue here. (for full code check image)

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Text as RNText } from 'react-native'
//...other imports

    const Text = (props) => {
      const {
        children,
        textProps,
        testIds,
      } = props
    
      return (
        <RNText
                {...testProps(testIds.textTestId)}
                {...textStyleProps(props)}
                allowFontScaling={false}
                maxFontSizeMultiplier={0}
                {...textProps}
        >
          {children}
        </RNText>
      )
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue?